# Finding determinants by inspection?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm supposed to "use properties of determinants to evaluate the determinant by inspection" on this matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 1& 3\\  
-2 & 0 &-2  \\
5 & 4 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

I don't see anything (zero rows, ways to transform the matrix) that would make it immediately obvious what the determinant is. What am I missing?

Comment: What does "by inspection" mean?

Comment: Use the second column. Doesn't it look simpler?

Comment: Subtract third column from first column.

Comment: In the other words: First column is the sum of the two remaining columns. This means that the columns are linearly dependent and the determinant is zero.

Answer (score 3):

Take the third column away from the first. This leaves column 1 and 2 equal, thus the determinant = 0

Answer (score 2):

If you subtract the third column from the first one, which is a valid transformation with respect to the determinant (it will leave it unchanged), you will get:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1& 3\\  
0 & 0 &-2  \\
4 & 4 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now it's clear that the first two columns are the same, and that means that the determinant must be $0$.

Addendum: if you are wondering why the determinant must be $0$ in this case, consider what would happen if we were to repeat the same process again, subtracting the second column from the first one.

Comment: Is there a reason why subtracting the third column from the first preserves the determinant?

Comment: @Trogdor Of course! [Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Effect_of_Elementary_Row_Operations_on_Determinant) is a more detailed explanation about the effects of row operations on the determinant of a matrix.